# Como obtener la clave/propiedad y el valor mas alto de un objeto

Tags: javascript

Buentas, tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
{      
  h: 1,
  o: 5,
  l: 3,
  a: 6,
  m: 3,
  i: 4,
  n: 3,
  b: 2,
  r: 4,
  e: 5,
  s: 3,
  y: 1,
  u: 1,
  v: 2,
  j: 1 
}
```

Como devuelven la letra que tiene el valor mas alto? es una prueba, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres encontrar específicamente la clave y el valor del máximo, podrías hacerlo así:

```js
var objeto = {
    h: 1,
    o: 5,
    l: 3,
    a: 6,
    m: 3,
    i: 4,
    n: 3,
    b: 2,
    r: 4,
    e: 5,
    s: 3,
    y: 1,
    u: 1,
    v: 2,
    j: 1
}

//Encontrar la clave del máximo
var claves = Object.keys(objeto); // Buscamos las claves del objeto ["h", "o", "l", "a", "m", "i", "n", ...]
var maximoClave = claves[0]; // Inicializamos a "maximoClave" como la primera posición del objeto => "h"

for (i = 0; i < claves.length; i++) {
    var value = claves[i]; // Recorremos todo el objeto
    if (objeto[value] > objeto[maximoClave]) maximoClave = value; // Encontramos el mayor valor y devolvemo la clave del mayor.
}

//Encontrar el valor del máximo
let valores = Object.values(objeto); // Buscamos los valores el objeto [1, 5, 3, 6, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1,...]
let maximoValor = Math.max(...valores); // Con la función "Math.max" devolvemos el valor máximo de lo buscado.

console.log(maximoClave, ":", maximoValor); // Imprimimos los resultados.
```

Answer (score 2):

Tendría que ser en tres pasos.

1. Encuentra el valor más alto de los `values`.
2. Filtrar el objeto para obtener el `key/value` desde `entries`
3. Convertir de nuevo a `objeto`

```js
const obj ={      
  h: 1,
  o: 5,
  l: 3,
  a: 6,
  m: 3,
  i: 4,
  n: 3,
  b: 2,
  r: 4,
  e: 5,
  s: 3,
  y: 1,
  u: 1,
  v: 2,
  j: 1 
}

const maxValue = Math.max(...Object.values(obj));

const filterEntries = Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => value === maxValue);

const filterObj = Object.fromEntries(filterEntries);

console.log(filterObj)
```

**Explicación**

`Math.max` nos ayuda a obtener el valor máximo de varios. Como solo nos interesa los valores de `values` convertimos todos los valores en un array con `Object.values(obj)` y los deconstruimos con `...`.

Después iteramos en `Object.entries`, que lo que hace es convertir `{a: 1, b: 2}` en `[[a, 1], [b, 2]]` y filtramos siempre que el valor sea el `maxValue`

El tercer paso `filterObj = Object.fromEntries(filterEntries);` nos convierte de `[[b, 2]]` a `{ b: 2}` una vez ya filtrado.

Answer (score 1):

No aclaras que sucede si el valor mas alto se repite, pero esto podria ser una solucion: converto el objeto en un array para poder aplicarle la funcion `sort`, ordeno de mayor a menor, obtengo el primer elemento y con él armo el resultado.

```js
const obj ={      
  h: 1,
  o: 5,
  l: 3,
  a: 6,
  m: 3,
  i: 4,
  n: 3,
  b: 2,
  r: 4,
  e: 5,
  s: 3,
  y: 1,
  u: 1,
  v: 2,
  j: 1 
}

let sortable = [];

for (var item in obj) {
    sortable.push([item, obj[item]]);
}

sortable.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);

const result = {
  [sortable[0][0]]: sortable[0][1]
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera que lo puedes hacer es utilizando un `reduce`:

```js
const obj = {      
  h: 1,
  o: 5,
  l: 3,
  a: 6,
  m: 3,
  i: 4,
  n: 3,
  b: 2,
  r: 4,
  e: 5,
  s: 3,
  y: 1,
  u: 1,
  v: 2,
  j: 1,
};

const highestKey = Object.keys(obj).reduce(
  (acc, cur) => obj[cur] > (obj[acc] || 0) ? cur : acc, '',
);

console.log(highestKey);
```